# How can I edit the custom options text in the created invoice PDF in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

OK, so we have this site that has a lot of custom options and we'd like to ideally have the label and value on the same line when the invoice PDF is created. I have located the file responsible at

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

and have made a copy at

app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

but my PHP is not good enough for me to figure out how to have the label and value on the same line.

This is the code in question:

```
$options = $this->getItemOptions();
    if ($options) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            // draw options label
            $lines[][] = array(
                'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                'font' => 'italic',
                'feed' => 35
            );

            if ($option['value']) {
                if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                    $_printValue = $option['print_value'];
                } else {
                    $_printValue = strip_tags($option['value']);
                }
                $values = explode(', ', $_printValue);
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    $lines[][] = array(
                        'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 30, true, true),
                        'feed' => 40
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ideally, I'd like to keep the checks and just have the 'text' be in this form:
'label' - 'value'

Thanks!